# Liftmaster garage door opens fine from remote but won't open at main button

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

My main button doesn't work by the door but my remote is working fine to open and close my garage door. I took off the main button and touched the wires together it still didn't work. The button has a light that just keeps flashing green. The garage door opener is flashing a code 3-2, 3 up 2 down.

The website says this about a code 3-2: "Garage door opener lost power: Check outlet the outlet for power. Run the opener open and close to clear the error code."

Help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: Did you follow the main button wires up to the unit and check/ short the connection there? Your wires could be bad.

Comment: How would you check/ short connection there?

Comment: The two wires that you touched together travel up to the unit and are fastened to two screws. Get a small piece of wire or a paper clip and touch both those screws

Comment: Thanks. Mine doesn't have screws up there, it has those little jacks you insert wires into. I did take them out and put them back in but nothing changed. Maybe I need figure out how to check the two wires running there.

Comment: Can you get a small piece of wire and stick it in both jacks?

Comment: Yeah I could do that. What should happen if it works? Is it just a reset?

Comment: You'd be shorting out the two jacks, same as pressing the main button. If the door operated, then your wires are bad.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'll try it out and report back

Comment: I don't see how the button could blink if it's wiring is disconnected or shorted.

Comment: I had a similar thought Dandavis. I got it fixed. I had to press the learn button and then press the garage door button to re-train it to recognize it. Worked great. Thanks for everyone'se help.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not a general discussion forum. One of the things we look for is _Answers_ to questions. If you would take a moment and make an answer out of your comment on how you fixed it, that will help others in the future who may have a similar problem - not everyone reads all the comments, and sometimes they get deleted...